# Scala implicits as explained by Odersky

Tags: scala

I'm reading the Odersky book on Scala implicits and I need some help understanding his example. I came across these passages:

> Java includes a library named Swing for implementing cross-platform user interfaces. One of the things Swing does is process events from the operating system, convert them to platform-independent event objects, and pass those events to parts of an application called event listeners...
>
> If Swing had been written with Scala in mind, event listeners would probably have been represented by a function type.

What does Odersky mean by function type? I know what event listeners are from writing jQuery and Javascript, but what does he mean by representing event listeners as a function type?

Next, his code examples are a bit unclear to me. The first one:

```
val button = new JButton

button.addActionListener(
 new ActionListener {
    def actionPerformed(event: ActionEvent) = {
      println("pressed")
    }
  }
)
```

So what is going on here? Are we passing an object with a method `actionPerformed` to the `addActionListener` method? What is going on here? How would one use this ActionListener?

Next, his reduced Scala friendly code is this:

```
button.addActionListener(
  (_: ActionEvent) => println("pressed")
)
```

We're passing an anonymous function to the `addActionListener` method. How would the underscore be used?

Lastly,

```
implicit def function2ActionListener(f: ActionEvent => Unit) =
 new ActionListener{
   def actionPerformed(event: ActionEvent) = f(event)
  }
```

So this implicit takes a function that takes in an `ActionEvent` and returns nothing. What does the `new` do here? What is it doing? Is it creating a method `actionPerformed` inside an instantiated object? What is going on?

Since these aren't full code examples, I'm having trouble seeing how they would be used and how it comes together. I'm also a bit lost as to what is going on in the code... like is a new object with a method being defined? Is the `actionPerformed` method being defined in a new object? Why? Can someone help a bit?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should probably refresh what an [anonymous inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) is, and how it is used in Java-centric frameworks for all kinds of callbacks.

> What does Odersky mean by function type?

The types of shape `(X1, ..., Xn) => Y`, implemented by traits
[`Function1[-X, +Y]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Function1.html), [`Function2[-X1, -X1, +Y]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Function2.html) and so on (up to 22 if I remember correctly, unless this restriction has been lifted by now).

> what does he mean by representing event listeners as a function type?

"Event listeners" are just special classes that take some kind of `Event`, and perform some action, usually returning `Unit`. This is essentially the same as the function type `Event => Unit`.

> What is going on here? How would one use this ActionListener?

As already mentioned above, we are instantiating an anonymous inner class with method `actionPerformed`, and install it as callback on some GUI-element.

> How would the underscore be used?

It isn't used at all. Underscore is specifically for arguments that aren't used. This is because this listener is a bit dumb, and simply prints out the same message every time, regardless of what the event is.

> So this implicit takes a function that takes in an `ActionEvent` and returns nothing.

The instance of the anonymous inner class implementing `ActionListener` needs the function `f` to implement the method `actionPerformed`, and from its signature you can see that it needs `Unit` as return type, because it just performs some side-effect action when it receives an `Event`, and doesn't need to return any meaningful values.

By the way: this last implicit conversion is now mostly obsolete because of SAM (single abstract method syntactic sugar).

Comment: Regarding last point I guess OP meant that the function returns nothing (actually Unit), so at this, he was rather correct. The implicit method given such function returns an action listener.